# Display blank value in referenced cells in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In an Excel sheet I have values in one cell populated by another cell, such as cell C2=A2

However, when cell A2 is blank cell C2's value is populated with a 0 (zero).

Is there anyway to make the C2 field simply be blank?

Answer (score 4):

This should fix your problem:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",A2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could even try in C2 `IF(A2="","",A2)`

Answer (score 0):

Merely changing the formatting, if feasible (say for a single, entire column) might suit. For example whereas `0.00` displays numbers and zero (to 2 2DP) `0.00;-0.00;` does not display  zero.

Further details [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-custom-number-format-HP001216503.aspx), including:

```
Create a custom number format

Open the workbook in which you want to create and store a custom number format.
On the Home tab, click the Dialog Box Launcher Button image next to Number.
In the Category box, click Custom.
In the Type list, select the number format that you want to customize.

The number format that you select appears in the Type box above the Type list.

 Note   When you select a built-in number format in the Type list, Excel creates a copy
 of that number format that you can then customize. The original number format in the
 Type list cannot be changed or deleted.
```

Although the same in superficial appearance, an empty cell and one containing "" may behave differently.

Comment: This does not leave it blank, but creates an actual number in the cell, meaning that if you have the value 0 in A2, it will still not display in C2, even though it had a value in A2. In other words, it assumes `0 = ""` which isn't true normally.